# SWT Browser not displaying pages using D3

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, swt

I would like to display a html page that uses D3 in an SWT Browser.

If I load a URL like `www.google.com` it loads correctly and allows me to search etc. If I try loading a page that contains D3 I find that nothing gets displayed and no errors are output.

**Example**

```
public class D3BrowserExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.addTitleListener(new TitleListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(TitleEvent event) {
        shell.setText(event.title);
        }
    });
    browser.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 900);
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    browser.setUrl("https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph");

    browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void completed(ProgressEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Page loaded");

        }

        @Override
        public void changed(ProgressEvent event) {
        }
    });
    
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to execute D3 using an SWT Browser? Also how can I get the Javascript output to debug the issue?

**Update**

I've tried this on another Windows 10 PC with version 4.3 of SWT. The `complete` method is called for the progress listener but nothing displays.

**Eclipse Bugzilla**

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568789

Comment: Seems to work OK on macOS. Just a few seconds delay at the start.

Comment: On Windows 10 I've had it running over 3 hours now and it's not loaded.

Comment: @greg-449 I've tried this in 4.6.1 and 4.10 for Windows 10 64bit and had the same issue. I've also tried loading a variety of pages using the browser built into Eclipse (I assume this uses the SWT Browser) and it can't load any d3 example pages. Is there any way I can go about debugging this or is it likely a problem with `Browser` that I won't be able to resolve?

Comment: I don't know anything about debugging this. You could maybe report the problem on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the best idea thank you